# Does CMake look into C/C++ source files for header files

Tags: cmake, makefile

It seems that CMake is looking into C source files to determine which header files are included. I could not find any mention of this behavior in documentation.

To test this hypothesis here is a simple example:

```
# project tree
$ ls
CMakeLists.txt  main.c  main.h
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(test_20 LANGUAGES C)

add_executable(main main.c)
target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

```c
// main.h - <empty file>

// main.c
#include <main.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf ("From main()\n");
}
```

Keeping everything the same, if I comment out the `#include <main.h>` line in `main.c`, the dependency on `main.h` gets removed.

1. With `#include <main.h>`:

`cat CMakeFiles/main.dir/depend.make` shows the following dependencies:

```
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o: ../main.h
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o: ../main.c
```

2. With `#include <main.h>` line commented:

`cat CMakeFiles/main.dir/depend.make` shows the following dependencies:

```
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o: ../main.c
```

Can anyone please explain or point to some documentation to explain this behavior.

PS: Checked with Ninja generator and GNU Makefiles generators.

Comment: The file `depend.make` is (re-)generated after all source files are compiled for a specific target (`main` in your case). This file is created from chunks which are generated by a gcc to contain a dependencies of the compiled source files. See more details in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74039255/3440745) to the duplicate question.